# Can the boxTidwell function handle binary outcome variables?

Tags: r

I initially wanted to run a `boxTidwell()` (found in the "car" package) analysis on my prospective Logistic Regression model (BinaryOutcomeVar ~ ContinuousPredVar + ContinuousPredVar^2 + ContinuousPredVar^3). I ran into issues:

```
Error in x - xbar : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

So, I created a reproducable example for demonstrating the error:

Doesn't work:

```
boxTidwell(formula = Treatment ~ uptake, other.x = ~ poly(x = colnames(CO2)[c(1,2,4)], degree = 2), data = CO2)
```

> boxTidwell(y = CO2$Treatment, x = CO2$uptake)

Works:

```
boxTidwell(formula = prestige ~ income + education, other.x = ~ poly(x = women , degree = 2), data = Prestige)
```

I've been goofing around with the `other.x` parameter and am guessing that's the issue.

**Question**

So, does anyone know if 1. the `boxTidwell()` function works with binary outcome variables 2. the logic behind the `other.x`, because I can't get my dummy example to work either.

Comment: So you expect us to go searching to find this function?

Comment: Uh, library(car)? Should I add that to the question?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you have a function from a non-default package you should include a `library` call that loads the package.

Comment: I just added it, thanks for the suggestion to improve my question.

Comment: So now it becomes clear after reading the `boxTidwell` documentation that you are thinking that this procedure will do a logistic regression just because the outcome is binary? And that call to poly looks really strange, with three variables one of which is an ordered factor. I think this is a doomed operation because `boxTidwell` does not do logistic regression and you are expecting way too much "mindreading" from the `poly` function.

Answer (score 0):

After further searching, it looks like the car:::boxTidwell can't handle the binary outcome variable in the formula, but it can be hand coded:

```
require(MASS)
require(car)

d1<-read.csv("path for your csv file",sep=',',header=TRUE)

x<-d1$explanatory variable name
y<-d1$dependent variable name

#FIT IS DONE USING THE glm FUNCTION
m1res <- glm(y ~ x,family=binomial(link = "logit"))
coeff1<- coefficients(summary(m1res))
lnx<-x*log(x)
m2res <- glm(y ~ x+lnx ,family=binomial(link = "logit"))
coeff2<- coefficients(summary(m2res))
alpha0<-1.0
pvalue<-coeff2[3,4]
pvalue
beta1<-coeff1[2,1]
beta2<-coeff2[3,1]
iter<-0
err<-1
while (pvalue<0.1) {
alpha <-(beta2/beta1)+alpha0 
err<-abs(alpha-alpha0)
alpha0<-alpha
mx<-x^alpha
m1res <- glm(y ~ mx,family=binomial(link = "logit"))
coeff1<- coefficients(summary(m1res))
mlnx<-mx*log(x)
m2res <- glm(y ~ mx+mlnx ,family=binomial(link = "logit"))
coeff2<- coefficients(summary(m2res))
pvalue<-coeff2[3,4]
beta1<-coeff1[2,1]
beta2<-coeff2[3,1]
iter<- iter+1
}
# PRINT THE POWER TO CONSOLE
alpha
```

above code taken from:
https://sites.google.com/site/ayyalaprem/box-tidwelltransform